# How to set timeoutSeconds options for a v2 firebase trigger function?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I have a Firestore trigger function defined as follows and wanted to define a timeout for it in the function definition code:

```
exports.myTriggerFunction = onDocumentCreated("users/{user_id}", async (event) => {

    // function body

})
```

For other functions it's easy, for example:

```
exports.nodeScrapeListings = onCall(

    { cors: true, timeoutSeconds: 540 },
    async () => {}
);
```

I am unsure of the syntax for doing this for a trigger function - could not find anything in the docs but may have missed something.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See the API documentation for [onDocumentCreated](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.md#firestoreondocumentcreated). The first argument may be a [DocumentOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.firestore.documentoptions.md#firestoredocumentoptions_interface) object, extended from [EventHandlerOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.eventhandleroptions.md#eventhandleroptions_interface) and [GlobalOptions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptions_interface). This allows for [timeoutSeconds](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/functions/2nd-gen/node/firebase-functions.globaloptions.md#globaloptionstimeoutseconds), among many other options common to various types of triggers.

```
exports.myTriggerFunction = onDocumentCreated(
    {
        document: "users/{user_id}",
        timeoutSeconds: X
    },
    async (event) => {
    }
)
```

There is no cors setting for Firestore functions since they can't be invoked directly from the browser like http functions.